# Push/pull docker images from a host computer

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, cicd, docker-in-docker

I'm using docker executor with DinD, and I was wondering if it's possible to store images that are built in a job to a host computer instead of Gitlab Container Registry? like for example, push/pull them to a host computer instead of the Gitlab Container Registry.

Comment: To a compliant registry it's possible. To a specific host, it should be possible but it will mean `scp` or something like that. What does your job look like?

Comment: A registry is just a host computer that you can push/pull images to. It sounds like you want to [deploy a registry server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)